# How to get the database context in a controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am trying all day to figure out to get the `ApplicationDbContext` in the `ManageController.cs` of a default MVC 6 project.

I went online and Googled a lot but no one seems to have the same problem as I have with it. It is probably simple but I can't figure it out. 
Anyone has an idea?

Here is what I tried:

```
IServiceProvider service = new IServiceProvider();
var _context = service.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use constructor injection:

```
public class ManageController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ManageController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `_context` object in your controller methods. There's more info in the [Dependency Injection](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html) section of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Some of the following steps might not be needed in the future release of Visual Studio.

1. Create ASP.NET Core (with .NET Core) project with `No Authentification`.
2. In Package Manager Console, execute each of the following, one after the other.

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
 Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre
 Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools -Pre
 Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc -Pre
```

3. Add the following to the `"tools":{}` defined in `project.json`.

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
```

4. Add the following to `appsettings.json`.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
```

5. Add the following to `ConfigureServices` in `startup.cs` right before `services.AddMvc();`.

```
string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<YourContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```